# How to accomplish client side validation on a partial view form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a new MVC5 that I started coding/learning with and in my view I call a partial view and in that partial view I have a form.

How can I validate my partial view client side so that the post doesn't occur if the model is invalid?

I am trying to use data annotations in my model.  I've had success elsewhere using them, but not in the case of a form post or partial view.

PartialView:

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyModel
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmmitPerson", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
            {                                        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="NAME" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(x => x.NAME).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control kendoTextBox" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="PHONE" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(x => x.PHONE).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control kendoTextBox" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ADDITIONALINFO" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Additional Information:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(x => x.ADDITIONALINFO).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control kendoTextBox" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            @(Html.Kendo().Button().Name("btnClose").Content("Cancel").Events(x => x.Click("btnClose_onClick")))
                            @(Html.Kendo().Button().Name("btnSave").Content("Save").Events(x => x.Click("btnSave_onClick")))
                        </div>
                    </div>
            }
```

My view model is:

```
public partial class MyModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        [Display(Name="Filter Name")]
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PHONE { get; set; }
        public string ADDITIONALINFO { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Include validation message html helper in your partial view and the 2 js files for client side validation

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  The post is still occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and add reference of 3 JavaScript named

(1)jquery-1.7.1.min.js (2) jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js  (3)  jquery.validate.min.js